# Page Scroll and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Using Codeigniter / PHP and [this Bootstrap template](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/). This template includes a page scroll feature on the home page.

I have a `header.php` template that will be used to display the main navigation on each page.

This main navigation code;

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#items">Items</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Jquery code;

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 100
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 50
        }
    })

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

Everything works as expected, but only on the home page (`home.php`).

I need to create some additional pages (e.g. `items.php`) this is where the header navigation doesn't work.

When I visit `items.php` and hover over the `Contact` menu link, the URL is `/items#contact`. It's looking for the `#contact` anchor on the `items` page. Instead I want to go to the `#contact` anchor on the `home` page.

So, in order to get this working I added `<?php echo base_url();?>` to my menu links - making them `<a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url();?>#items">Items</a>`. My home page URL is `http://localhost/ci`

This works, and when on the `items` page successfully takes me to the correct anchor on the `home page`.

However it seems like after adding `<?php echo base_url();?>`, the home page scroll doesn't work. Clickiong the links takes me to the correct anchor, but instead of scrolling it 'jumps'.

Probably something very simple! Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide a live link? (Unless it's localhost)

Comment: Hi since you are providing base url, the page might be getting reloaded or else the page scroll plugin only required anchor id. Check `http://mylogisticz.com/ ` has similar thing as you want. Home has page scroll but if u click on read more anchor tag href changes from id's to url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function. It uses javascript pathname to find if the current page is homepage. If the current page is homepage it will scroll to the desired position or else it will navigate to the homepage. (Use your homepage pathname instead of "/")

```js
 (function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
  /*******USE YOUR HOMEPAGE PATHNAME HERE*****/
  if(window.location.pathname == '/') {
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   var hash = url.split('#')[1];
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
     scrollTop: ($('#' + hash).offset().top - 50)
    }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
   }
        
    });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

Comment: Can you give me your homepage URL?

Comment: The following line should be:
if(window.location.pathname == '/ci' || window.location.pathname == '/ci/') {

Are you using this as your pathname?

Comment: Do you mean other page aren't navigating to homepage?

Comment: Please also post your navigation code. Are you appending base url to it or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139483/discussion-between-shr3jn-and-johnny-s).